# Dynamically set width & height in Videogular

Tags: responsive-design, html5-video, videogular

I'm using Videogular. I want to set Height & Width dynamically. how do i set the value

```
videojs.options.width = sizeWidth;
videojs.options.height = sizeHeight;
```

is this right way to set width & height for videogular?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically resize `Videogular` in a responsive website you can set `vg-responsive="true"` and `Videogular` will fit in its container.

However, if you want to change manually the size you must change the properties that you've binded to `vg-width` and `vg-height`, like you're doing in your code. Maybe your HTML is wrong, so this is how it should looks like:

```
<videogular vg-width="videojs.options.width" vg-height="videojs.options.height" vg-responsive="false" vg-theme="config.theme.url">
    <video vg-src="videojs.options.sources" preload='metadata'>
        <!-- You can also have sources here and remove vg-src="videojs.options.sources" -->
    </video>
</videogular>
```

Comment: i set vg-responsive="true" . it doesn't work. i also passed theme too.

Comment: Could you please post somewhere an example to take a look to the code?

Comment: Parent page HTML :  <iframe
           src="eplayer.html?width=720&height=405"
           scrolling="no"
           style="border: 0; margin:0; padding:0; width: 1000px; height: 700px;"
           allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen>
          </iframe>                                             child page HTML: <video 
        id="videogular" 
        class="video-js" 
  vg-responsive="true"
        controls autoplay 
        preload="auto">
      </video>

Comment: is this code rgt?. in browser can view the binding line vg-reponsive="true"